# Cannot implicitly convert string[][] to string[] in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm getting this error in `new` keyword.

//Code:

```
  public static string[] SplitStrings(string inboundString, char splitChar)
        {
            if(inboundString.Contains(splitChar))
            {
                return new[] { inboundString.Split(splitChar) };
            }
        }
```

Comment: Since `String.Split()` method returns an array, you are creating an array of arrays. Just remove `new []` and you should be fine. And you need to return another array (an empty array maybe) for your else part to prevent _not all code paths return a value_ error.

Comment: Why do you use `if(inboundString.Contains(splitChar))` at all? That costs CPU time for no added value. or do you want to return something else if `inboundString` doesn't contain the char?

Comment: In fact, why not just call `inboundString.Split(splitChar)` in the calling code?  Does this function add any additional value?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: if it doesnt contains dont it throw an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create a new array the return from split works just fine.

```
public static string[] SplitStrings(string inboundString, char splitChar)
     {
        if(inboundString.Contains(splitChar))
        {
            return inboundString.Split(splitChar);
        }
        else 
        {
          return new string[] {};
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this

```
        public static string[] SplitStrings(string inboundString, char splitChar)
        {               
             return inboundString.Split(splitChar);               
        }
```

String.Split itself returns a string[] so you don`t need to initialize a new one.

Comment: How can i handle the else part? any ideas??

Comment: @SanthoshKumar, it depends on what you want to return if the split character is not found in your string

Comment: @SanthoshKumar - Hogan`s idea of returning new string[] {}; will be good enough

Comment: Will that return my value if split char is not found?

Comment: @SanthoshKumar - see the modified method. It will return the spllited string if splitChar is not empty. And it will return string[] {inboundString} if it is.